# Normal velocity direction

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, string

> Lets say i have an object attached to rope and it starts spinning in a way that rotation happens in $x,y$ plane consider $y=0$ being ground level. It has tangent velocity of $v_0$. Now how large $v_0$ has to be in order to keep spinning (without falling out of it's circle trajectory).

[image]

I have a example of this situation from text book. Now the thing i don't understand is the direction of $\hat{a_n}$ in the picture. Is this simply false or am i missing something ?

To my knowledge the condition that the object can keep spinning on it's circle trajectory is that normal acceleration $a_n$ has to be at least equal to the acceleration caused by gravity. Meaning force caused by normal velocity ($m_a\cdot m$) needs to be facing opposite direction compared to gravity. Which isn't the case in this picture ?

The text book provides also the equation for this situation. (The condition that the object will keep spinning on it's trajectory)

By newton's II law

$$ \hat{G}=m\hat{a}_n $$
When normal velocity is $a_n\frac{v_0^2}{r}$
$$ mg=m\frac{v^2}{r} $$
$$ g=\frac{v^2}{r} $$
$$ v=\sqrt{rg} $$

---

Now if someone can understand this better than i do please explain whats going on with this. Also if you think this image is simply false let me know.

Answer (score 1):

The solution from the book is correct.

The key idea is that, since you're in a gravitational field, the tension is no longer constant. IF it were horizontal, tension would be constant.

But this time tension won't be constant. In the upper point, you'll have $a_n=T+g$, while in the lowest point you've got $a_n=T-g$.

If you want to have a uniform circular movement, then $a_n$ must be constant (in fact, $a_n=v_0^2/r$).

So the reasoning is... what is the **minimum** tension to allow the circular movement? The minimum one is such that doesn't contribute in the upper part (so upside you only have $g$), but the tension will become 2g below, so that $a_n$ can be constant $(=g)$ all along the circle.